# How many successful Soyuz launches have there been?

Tags: launch, spacecraft, soyuz-launcher

From the first Soyuz to the launch vehicles used today, how many launches have been deemed successful?

Comment: Successful just on the launch or successful mission?

Comment: I suggest [Jonathan's Space Report - Master Orbital Launch Log](http://planet4589.org/space/log/launch.html) as a source to collate this data from. "Soyuz" is however a rather broad term, even if we only count the launch vehicles themselves, with the [Soyuz rocket family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_(rocket_family)) counting [4 different and still operational vehicles, 5 already retired members, and one under development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_orbital_launch_systems). So I suggest running a few different subtotals on the mentioned launch log data for the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**As of Sep 24 2013:**

The *TsSKB Progress* site gives [the official numbers](http://en.samspace.ru/products/launch_vehicles/launch_vehicles_stat/) for all of the R-7 family.

Now, counting only rockets designated Soyuz, that is:

Soyuz-ST,
Soyuz-2,
Soyuz-U,
Soyuz-FG,
Soyuz-U2,
Soyuz-M,
Soyuz-L,
Soyuz.

And not counting Vostok, Molnia, Voskhod, Sputnik and R7 MBR, we have

total: 5+23+778+44+70+8+3+32 = 963

failure: 1+21+2 = 24

**success:** 963 - 24 = **939**